# Support ArcGIS tileMap variable-zoom file within Mapbox-GL-JS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, zoom, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to consume vector tiles and style file generated by ArcGIS, in Mapbox-GL-JS. With a bit of tweaking, it all works, except that the vector tiles themselves have been generated to varying zoom levels, which are documented in a [VectorTilemap](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/vector-tilemap.htm) file.

Mapbox-GL-JS doesn't natively support any kind of variable zoom depth in vector tiles.

I see that I am [not the first person](https://gist.github.com/jgravois/51e2b30e3d6cf6c00f06b263a29108a2#file-index-html-L56) to encounter this issue.

Is there any possible way to use these vector tiles in Mapbox-GL-JS? Any clever workarounds?